# Why do I need to call a method before receiving signals in allJoyn?

Tags: java, alljoyn

I am trying to implement a signal handler in [AllJoyn](https://allseenalliance.org/framework) using the Java binding.

I have defined a BusInterface:

```
@BusInterface(name = "net.allplay.MediaPlayer")
public interface MediaPlayerInterface {

    @BusMethod(name = "GetPlaylist", replySignature = "a(ssssxsssa{ss}a{sv}v)ss")
    public Playlist getPlaylist() throws BusException;

    @BusProperty(name = "PlayState")
    public PlayState getPlayState() throws BusException;

    @BusSignal(name = "PlaylistChanged")
    public void onPlaylistChanged() throws BusException;

    @BusSignal(name = "PlayStateChanged")
    public void onPlayStateChanged(PlayState playState) throws BusException;
```

and an according BusSignalHandler method in another class (`MediaPlayerSignalHandler`):

```
@BusSignalHandler(iface = "com.test.MediaPlayerInterface", signal = "onPlaylistChanged")
    public void onPlaylistChanged() {
        System.out.println("Play list changed");
    }
```

Finally I create a session, get the ProxyBusObject and the interface

```
sessionId = new Mutable.IntegerValue();
busAttachment.enableConcurrentCallbacks();
busAttachment.joinSession(busName, port, sessionId, createSessionOptions(), new SessionListener());
busAttachment.getProxyBusObject(busName, "/net/allplay/MediaPlayer", sessionId.value,
    new Class<?>[] { MediaPlayerInterface.class });
mediaPlayerInterface = allPlayObject.getInterface(MediaPlayerInterface.class);
busHandler.getBusAttachement().registerSignalHandlers(new MediaPlayerSignalHandler());
```

Now, no signals are received even though the remote device changed its PlayState.
Only after calling a method on the remote device once (e.g. `mediaPlayerInterface.getPlaylist()`), all signals are received correctly.

I don't think allJoyn is designed this way, so I'm wondering what I might be doing wrong here. Any ideas?

Comment: did you call `enableConcurrentCallbacks()` from the `busAttachment`?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, unfortunately I am already calling this method... updated the above question to include the related code snippet

Comment: I suspect that the signal handler object created by `new MediaPlayerSignalHandler()` is garbage collected. Try to store it for instance in a private field.

Comment: Hi, good idea, however no change... Still need to call a method before signals are coming in.